# Problems with µ, displaying ţ with sisetup option (for combination of siunitx, fontspec and kpfonts)

Tags: fontspec, siunitx, kpfonts

I have problems with the combination of using siunitx and displaying upright partial derivative symbols using:

```
\usepackage[partialup]{kpfonts}
```

The unit prefix µ is not displayed using this code:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[partialup]{kpfonts}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\micro\meter}
\end{document}
```

Adding the line

```
\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}
```

as mentioned on this board will display a ţ instead of a µ.

[image]

I've no idea how to solve that problem and would aprecciate your help.

Comment: @campa wouldn't kp work just fine in xelatex and lualatex, just ditch fontspec (on tablet so cannot test)

Comment: Using T1 fonts with LuaTeX/XeTeX is not generally a great plan, and that's what's happening here. `siunitx` is looking for a symbol that does not exist, as with these Unicode engines it goes with 'just use a µ' as the standard position. (The ţ _is_ a µ, or at least it's in that slot in the T1-encoded text font you are using.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering Joseph Wright's comment I tried to avoid `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. This resulted in a warning for a undefined font shape due to the `\usepackage[partialup]{kpfonts}` command.

Looking for a solution without kpfonts I found the package unicode-math, which allows upright partial derivative symbols as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\micro\meter}

$\frac{\symrm{\partial} Q}{\partial t}=\mu$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope, this solution will not effect other problems.

Comment: only this solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This also worked for me using an ArXiv template.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work.
The primary/only relevant? change is explicitly setting `math-micro` to `\mu` via `\sisetup`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[uprightgreeks,partialup]{kpfonts}


\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    math-micro = \mu,
 }

\begin{document}
    \SI{1}{\micro \meter}

    \SI{1}{\micro \gram}

    \SI{1}{\kilo \gram}

    \SI{1}{\nano \gram}

    \si{\gram}

    \begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial s}{\partial t} % just testing the partial ups
    \end{equation}

    \si{\micro \gram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works so far. However now all greek letters in my document will be upright although it is not wanted for parameters. `\textit{}` does not help at this point.